# How to run selenium test first and automatically deploy my code using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, selenium-webdriver, continuous-integration, testng, bitbucket

I want to do setup for jenkins. SO that it will first run my selenium tests. If its succeed only then it deploy my code to server. Also I am using bitbucket for code commit

Comment: look into jenkins declarative pipelines, add a stage that runs your selenium test, and then another stage to deploy your code. subsequent stages only run when the preceding stages succeed.

Comment: Which server(Like jboss) are you using? and which build tool like ant or Maven?